# How can I append some text to a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery and I need to append some text to a variable:

```
$("document").ready(function(){
  var i="this is text";
$(i).append("aa");
  alert(i);
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xabsgzx9/)

Comment: [I think there's a jQuery plugin for that](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif)

Comment: @Juhana - was just looking for that one, it seems to fit perfectly here!

Comment: @Juhana you don't even need a plugin for that. It's just concatenating strings?

Comment: @Grimbode: Follow the link (it's safe, trust me).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I see what he did there. The humor with Juhana is strong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could of course create a jQuery plugin for this

```js
$.fn.appendString = function(str) {
    return this.selector + str;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var i = "this is text";

    alert( $(i).appendString("aa") );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

But it's concantenating strings

```
var i = "this is text";

i = i + "aa"; // it's now "this is textaa"
```

Note that `$("this is text")` is not really valid anything, jQuery doesn't really proccess strings